# Space between legend items

Tags: r, lattice

I'm using R and the `lattice` package to plot the chart below.

Notice the two items in the legend, that are shown with no spacing between them. If I show the legend above (or below) the chart, it's shown with some space between them, but not if I show in on the right. Is there any way I can separate the two items a bit?

The code used to produce this figure is also reproduced below.

[image: Example]

```
barchart(val1 ~ val2, groups=group, tasks, 
         auto.key=list(
           columns=1, 
           space="right", 
           text=c("Data 1","Data 2")
           ), 
         main="Title",
         xlab="Tasks", ylab="Duration",
         par.settings=list(superpose.polygon=list(col=c("firebrick","dodgerblue2"))) 
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think padding.text ist what you are looking for. I dont know, if that works with auto.key.

```
attach(mtcars)
gear.f<-factor(gear,levels=c(3,4,5),
labels=c("3gears","4gears","5gears"))
cyl.f <-factor(cyl,levels=c(4,6,8),
labels=c("4cyl","6cyl","8cyl"))

densityplot(~mpg|cyl.f,
    main="Density Plot by Number of Cylinders",
    xlab="Miles per Gallon"
   ,par.settings = list(superpose.line = list(col=c(1,2,3)))
   ,key = list(text = list(c("A", "B", "C")),lines = list(col=c("black", "red", "green")),
              columns=1,space="top",padding.text=4
             )
        )
```

Comment: This works but only for keys set as columns, modifying the space vertically. What if I want to display the key items horizontally?